# Strict order of points within a tolerance on a 2d plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I have a situation that I want to define a strict order of the points on a 2d plane, such that point1 < point2, which point is represented by (x, y) in real number. I also want that two points are equal if they are close enough, say, in a tolerance.

My initial intention is to use the dictionary order of x and y like below to define the order of points,

1. If x1 < x2, then point1 < point2
2. If x1 == x2 and y1 < y2, then point1 < point2
3. If x1 == x2 and y1 == y2, then point1 == point2
4. The equality is defined within a tolerance, e.g. a == b if a - b < tolerance

But, quickly I realize that strict order defined above will cause following contradiction, e.g. I have three points, p1, p2 and p3, satisfying

1. x1 == x2 and y1 == y2 both in a tolerance, then p1 == p2
2. x2 == x3 and y2 == y2 both in a tolerance, then p2 == p3
3. x1 < x3 (as x3 - x1 > tolerance), then p1 < p3
4. So, it turns to p1 == p3 and p1 < p3, which is wrong. The transitivity can't work.

Then, I come to another thought,

1. Define a many-to-one mapping from real number to integer number by a given tolerance, e.g. if the tolerance is 0.1, then any value ranging from (0 ~ 0.1] maps to 1, similarly (0.1 ~ 0.2] maps to 2, and so on.
2. Then, each coordinate of point (x, y) can map to (a, b) which a and b are all integers.
3. Finally, determine the order of points strictly based on the dictionary order of integer numbers.

I am not sure whether my though is feasible, especially I want to program them in real case. And, if it can work, what is the mapping should I take from real number range to a integer number? Or any other good suggestions on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to see the problem if we just work in one dimension.  There is the usual order on $\Bbb R$, but if you define $a==b$ if $|a - b|\lt t$, where $t$ is your tolerance, then the transitivity of equality forces all numbers to be equal.  Take a number $a$, let $b=a+\frac 34t, c=b+\frac 34t$.  Then $a==b==c,$ but $|a-c|=\frac 32t$

It gets even worse in 2D with the dictionary order, as you see.  In that order, points with different $x$ values are very far apart, no matter how small the difference in $x$.  You are collapsing them together.

For your idea of collapsing reals to integers, you will always have cases where reals that are close together map to different integers.  In your example $0.0999$ maps to $1$, but $0.1001$ maps to $2$, which is contrary to what you want everywhere else.

Comment: Yes, I see that reals are close but still map to different integers. I think this is something I have to compromise, so as to make the order relationship working consistently.